# pythonを使って､Windows10上の｢名前の変更ができないファイル/フォルダ｣の判定はできますか？

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

実際に変更してみて(あるいはコピーの作成を試みるなどして)try/exceptするのではなく
st_file_attributesで属性確認 等､何らかの値を取得して判定することはできるでしょうか？

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかも。[Get file attributes (hidden, readonly, system, archive) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27196143/9014308), [python os.listdir() shows protected files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12129892/9014308)

Comment: [What process is using a given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39637414) では handle.exe を使って調べています(`subprocess` による外部コマンドの実行)。

Comment: hidden readonly systemはほぼ役立つのですが､例えばc\ProgrammFiles(x86)は"重要だ"と見なす一方c\ProgrammFilesは通常のフォルダと同じ判定をしてしまいます. 実際にはどちらも名前の変更はできません

Comment: その判定がアトミックで無いことを承知した上での質問でしょうか？仮に判定直後でもリネームが成功する保証はありませんよ

Comment: リネームのために判定をしたい､とは書いていませんよ｡何が言いたいのでしょうか？

Comment: おそらく1つの方法だけで全てに通用するものは無いのでしょう。[Filename - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)にある予約名、@metropolisさんコメントのように誰かがOpen中であるとか、Windows Defenderとかウイルスチェックプログラムによる保護[フォルダー アクセスを制御して重要なフォルダーを保護する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/controlled-folders?view=o365-worldwide)等色々な状況があり、その全てがAPIで取得できるとも限りません。またDirectory/Fileのアクセス権情報取得(例えば[File.GetAccessControl メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8))のように、権利を有していない結果が例外で通知されるAPIも考えられます。